# Cannot access form from Scope AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, scope

I have the following

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-inline" >
<div class="container-fluid  ">
<input ng-class="{'requiredError':programNameError}" name="first" ng-model="ProgramDetail.ProgramName" placeholder="Name" class="form-control input-xs" type="text" style="width:70%" />
</div>
</form>
```

This page is being called by the ngRoute when I navigate to a specific route and I specify the controller in the route configuration, buen when I try to access the $scope.myForm i get undefined.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you show your controller code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the form a `name` attribute to expose it on the `$scope`

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" class="form-inline" >

</form>
```

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form):

> If the name attribute is specified, the form controller is published
>   onto the current scope under this name.

Answer (score 1):

Argh, not enough reputation to write a comment, so writing as an answer.. :(

try defining the attribute `name` for the form.. I have a similar case and it worked only with this..

```
<form id="myForm" class="form-inline" name="myForm">
</form>
```